# How to use jQuery has() with checkbox input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to apply a class name to a div only if the div contains at least one checkbox input.

I'm trying this code, but it does not work:

```
('.product-info .buy .options .option-r').has('input[type="checkbox"]').addClass( 'contains_checkbox' );
```

But at another location, I tried it with select, and it worked:

```
('.product-info .buy .options .option-r').has('select').addClass( 'contains_select' )
```

How do I make it work for checkboxes too ? And only checkboxes, not other types of input ..

Comment: Provide us with a jsFiddle replicating the problem, it should work fine.

Comment: Your code looks correct minus the missing jQuery call

Comment: I can't post code as such because the whole code is system generated .. Extracting relevant code will be a *major* task in itself ..

Comment: False alarm ! I forgot to write the jQuery '$' sign in the start .. :) .. Writing that fixed the issue .. Mods can close this thread if they wish :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.product-info .buy .options .option-r').has('input:checkbox').addClass( 'contains_checkbox' );
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle it will be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: False alarm ! I forgot to write the jQuery '$' sign in the start .. :) .. Writing that fixed the issue .. Mods can close this thread if they wish :)